# Oracle Enterprise Manager and Intelligent Agents

Tags: java, oracle, jms, weblogic

I was wondering if an intelligent agent can be used to start/stop a java program on an external machine through the Enterprise Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it could - don't know about that - I would not advise to do that.
If you want to start a job on a remote machine, use Oracle Scheduler to do that, using Remote Job Agent and credentials.
In Oracle 9i Enterprise Manager it was possible to do it. Learned a lot from it: don't use the Intelligent Agent, use Oracle Scheduler instead.

Comment: So are you advising against using the Oracle Scheduler with Remote Job Agent or to use the oracle scheduler with Remote Job Agent?

Comment: No, don't use Intelligent Agent, part or GridControl/Enterprise Manager.Use the Remote Scheduler Agent from the Oracle Scheduler.